# Why am I unable to import this CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, file, path

In Jupyter notebook, I'm trying to import a csv file containing a list of stocks.

```
import numpy as np
import requests
import xlsxwriter
from scipy import stats
import math
import secrets

#import the list of stocks from csv file on my system
#https://datahub.io/core/s-and-p-500-companies#data

stocks = pd.read_csv('constituents.csv')
from secrets import IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ce2cd0ea5cfb> in <module>
      3 
      4 
----> 5 stocks = pd.read_csv('constituents.csv')
      6 from secrets import IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Please help!

Comment: import pandas as pd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is :

```
import pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use pandas library without importing it.

You should add at the beginning of your script:

```
import pandas as pd
```

if you don't have pandas, you should install it using:

```
pip install pandas
```